# Center horizontally block element which has dynamic width - CSS only cross browser

Tags: html, css

This is an ancient topic, but I swear it is proving more difficult than it should be.

I have created a jsfiddle to show the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/VfDfw/1/

I thought I cracked it, but it fails in IE 8 compatibility mode.

**The Problem**

I have navigation menu, in a symantic un-ordered list. The div wrapper which contains has a fixed width which is the main width of the website.

The un-ordered list needs to float central in the wrapper. But none of the block elements in the navigation have a set width.

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/VfDfw/1/

I have coloured each element a different background color so you can see each element.

I thought I found a fix buy having half the wrapper width on **div.nav** as a left position, and then -50% margin-left on **.nav ul** - but seems to fail in IE 8 compatibility mode, see fiddle below...

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/VfDfw/2/

Can anyone suggest a solution or a more efficient CSS method. It is baking my noodle.

Thanks

---

**Update**

I thought I should update my question with why I am using each div in my fiddle example.

See my new fiddle. [http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/VfDfw/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/VfDfw/4/)

I have now added a top position of 10px to each element so you can see the purpose of why I have used so many divs. But the only problem is that this solution is not IE 7 friendly. So I need another solution of centering block elements. I wish there was a **float: center** CSS rule!

[image]

1. The dark blue **div** is my horizon 100% width div for my navigation infinite background image.
2. The red **div** is the wrapper which is the maximum width of my website. Fiddle width: 420px.
3. The green **div** is the floated width of my dynamic nav, positioned left: 210px (50% of above width)
4. The yellow **ul** is the floated width of my dynamic nav **li** elements, with negative margin of 50%
5. The blue **li**'s are my anchor button containers with dividers.

I hope this makes sense. But this solution nearlly worked but it's a shame it does not work IE7

Comment: Do you really need so many wrappers? Are all of them is need to show the problem?

Comment: Hm, I wonder if you check your analytics what % of visits are from IE? You could always check a website with a similar layout to see how they have done it? Maybe simplifying the example would make this easier.

Comment: @vladmir - the horizon is needed for nav background color, the wrapper is needed to center the maximum width area. Everything else after can be modified, but I can't figure out anyway to centralise the nav buttons within the wrapper.

Comment: @CodeBlend - its trying to find a website that uses the same technique. All my buttons have to fully be HTML as they are generated via a CMS

Answer (score 0):

Using display block and inline-block with text-align center could help you. It used to work in very old browsers. Change the block to inline-block in the wrapper, nav, ul to make them go full width o "shrink" and center. (Can`t check the fiddle in old IE, but "should" work)

When you center text in a div and the text is not really text, but inline-blocks, they behave like if they where 'words', making the content a centered list of elements without need of any fixed width.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#horizon {
    height: 49px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visable;
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/nav-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top #041e75;
    top: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 420px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    height: 49px;
    overflow: visible;
    background: red;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav {
    display:block;
    height: 49px;
    background: green;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav ul {
    background: yellow;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    overflow: visible;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 49px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(6, 29, 93 );
    background-color: rgba(13, 43, 119, 0.95);
}
```

```html
<div id="horizon">
    
    <div id="wrapper">
    
        <div class="nav">                
        
            <ul>
        
                <li><a href="#" title="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="menu">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="map">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="contact">Contact</a></li>
        
            </ul>
    
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi I try my way with flex
in my opinion, the flex display is the best way to do it
I explained in the lines how to use it.

```
    body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#horizon {
    height: 49px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visable;
    background: url(images/nav-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top #041e75;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 420px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    height: 49px;
    overflow: visible;
    background: red;    
    width: 100%;

}

.nav {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 49px;
    float: left;
    left: 210px;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav ul{
  /* useflex to make them to be as a row */
  display: flex;
  /* remove the points from the ul */
  list-style: none;
  /* use this to chose how to spreate the content */
  justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

a {
  /* remove text dec for the li */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you might want to try the "margin 0 auto" technique with a "fit-content width" as follow:

```
.nav { 
      overflow: visible; 
      height: 49px; 
      position: relative; 
      background: green; 
}

.nav ul {
    height: 49px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px white solid;
    margin-left: -50%;
    top: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
    background: yellow;
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: fit-content; 
}
```

hope this works.